# Bayesian optimization with offline stochastic function and sticky decisions

Tags: dataset, noise, bayesian-optimization

Is there a Bayesian optimization (BO) framework which allows:

1. Warm start with offline data.
2. The stochastic function $f(x)$ is noisy.
3. Every iteration is $n$ samples controlled by agent and there are constrains on $\min n$ (or maybe penalty).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, all BO implementations should support this because it only fits the underlying GP. It is not difficult and straightforward.
2. Yes. Again, the observation is supposed to be noisy, and hence the term $(\mathbf{K} + \sigma^2 \mathbf{I})^{-1}$, where $\sigma^2$ accounts for the Gaussian noise. Note that this does assume Gaussian noise $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.
3. There is no agent involved in BO (at least in the conventional settings) unless one modifies it.